# Linked list in javascript

Tags: javascript

how this.tail.next = newNode is adding the value to next property of head? if it isn't then what part of the code is responsible to add next value to head?

```
  constructor(value) {
    this.head = {
      value: value,
      next: null
    }
    this.tail = this.head;
    this.lenght = 1;
  }
  append(value) {
    let newNode = {
      value: value,
      next: null 
    }
    this.tail.next = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
    this.lenght++;
    return this;
  }


}


let myList = new LinkedList(10);
myList.append(8);
myList.append(8);
```

Output

````
  head: { value: 10, next: { value: 8, next: [Object] } },
  tail: { value: 8, next: null },
  lenght: 3
}```
````

Comment: `this.lenght++;` `this.lenght = 1;`spelling error

Answer (score 0):

The 'this.tail = this.head' part of your code is making 'this.tail' a reference to 'this.head'. what you want is to make it a copy of 'this.head'.

see here: [JavaScript: How to make a copy of a object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664115/javascript-how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-object).

Comment: Not actually, it's deliberately making `this.head` and `this.tail` properties refer to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code has a problem in that it can't create an empty list. Normally a forward linked list maintains both head and tail pointers so that

- The head pointer points to the first node in the list,
- The tail pointer points to the last entry in the list,
- If the list is empty, both head and tail pointers are `null`,
- If the list contains a single element, the head and tail pointers are the same (and point to the only node in the list).
- Each node points to the next node in the list.
- A two way linked list would maintain both `previous` and `next` node values.

In the following example, `length` still maintains the number of elements in the list to simplify checking if the list is empty.

```js
class ForwardLinkedList {
    constructor(...values) {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
        values.forEach( value => this.append(value));
    }
    append( value) {
        let newNode = {
            value: value,
            next: null 
        }
        if( this.length) {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            this.tail = newNode;
        }
        else {
            this.head = this.tail = newNode;
        }
        ++this.length;
    }
}

let myList = new ForwardLinkedList(10);
myList.append(8);
myList.append(6);
console.log(JSON.stringify( myList));
```

Answer (score 0):

````
 head: { value: 10, next: { value: 8, next: [Object] } },
  tail: { value: 8, next: null },
  lenght: 3
}```
````

I guess your confusion is, why it is written like `this.tail.next = newNode`
remember previously a reference of `this.head` was set to `this.tail` so in that sense, a copy of `this.head` was inside the `this.tail`. Now if we simply write `this.tail` which is `tail: { value: 8, next: null }` that is the last item in our list because the method doesn't know that we only have one item. So it's going to grab the tail and then grab the next value of tail `this.tail.next`, so it's going to grab the pointer of the tail and say hey instead of pointing at to `null` point it to a new node that we just created.
Finally we update the `this.tail = newNode;`